# Strange integration #2

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, bugs, symbolic, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 10**

---

I was working on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395145/153012). On *Mathematica 9* for the query

```
N[Integrate[(ArcSin[x])/Sqrt[2*x - x^2], {x, 0, 1}], 50]
```

I've got the answer

```
4.3490873650146277599014049625438707032244466030283
```

which seems to be incorrect. It seems that the query without the `N[]` part gives an incorrect analytic solution too.
For

```
NIntegrate[(ArcSin[x])/Sqrt[2*x - x^2], {x, 0, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

I've got the answer

```
0.64368050414630466770404234158695708461111179796355
```

which seems to be correct. Any idea what happened here?

Comment: Can confirm; bug is no longer present in versions 10 and 11. Interestingly version 5 also returns a different result: `5.578...`

Comment: @J.M. Does version 10 or 11 give a correct analytic solution too?

Comment: The result of `Integrate[]` in version 11 gives a result consistent with that of `NIntegrate[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Could you give me the result of `Integrate[]`? You can write it as an answer, or link in a comment.

Comment: After simplification I get `π^2/8 + π/6 (3 ArcCoth[Sqrt[3]] + Hypergeometric2F1[3/4, 3/4, 7/4, (2 - Sqrt[3])/4]/(2 + Sqrt[3])^(3/4)) - (2 Gamma[3/4]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 1/4, 3/4, 3/4}, {1/2, 5/4, 5/4}, 1/4] + Gamma[1/4]^2/72 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 3/4, 5/4, 5/4}, {3/2, 7/4, 7/4}, 1/4])/Sqrt[π]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"  *)

f[x_] = ArcSin[x]/Sqrt[2*x - x^2];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
int = Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify

(*  π^2/8 + 
 1/6 π (3 ArcCoth[Sqrt[3]] + 
    Hypergeometric2F1[3/4, 3/4, 7/4, 
     1/4 (2 - Sqrt[3])]/(2 + Sqrt[3])^(3/4)) - (1/(9 Sqrt[π]))
 2 (9 Gamma[3/
      4]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 1/4, 3/4, 3/4}, {1/2, 5/4, 5/4}, 1/
      4] + Gamma[5/
      4]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 3/4, 5/4, 5/4}, {3/2, 7/4, 7/4}, 1/
      4])  *)

int // N[#, 50] &

(*  0.64368050414630466770404234158695708461111179796355  *)

NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]

(*  0.64368050414630466770404234158695708461111179796355  *)
```